# Bash script to zip files and folders with matching names to another directory

Tags: bash, shell, zip

I have many folders and files of the following type:

```
├── name 1.htm
├── name 2.html
├── name 1_files 
│   ├── some files
├── name 2_files 
│   ├── some files
```

I need for each .htm or .html file to find the appropriate folder with the same name, but with a  "_files" at the end.

Then I need to put the found file and folder in another folder, for example, '000' and zip it.

Then I need to move the resulting .zip file to another folder, for example, 'Found'.

I'm a newbie to bash and scripting in general so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a zip-by-prefix.sh script that you can run from the directory where the the htm* files are present :

```
mkdir -p found
ls *.htm* > htmlfiles.txt
cat htmlfiles.txt | cut -d"." -f1 | uniq > htmlprefixes.txt
PREFIXES=$(echo `cat htmlprefixes.txt`)
for prefix in $PREFIXES
do 
mkdir -p 000$prefix
cp $prefix* 000$prefix
zip -r 000$prefix.zip 000$prefix
mv 000$prefix.zip found
done
rm *.txt
```

Explanation

- Line 1 : Create the **found** directory if it does not exist
- Line 2-4 : Extract the htm or html **unique prefixes** to a PREFIXES variable
- Line 5-11 : Loop through PREFIXES variable array to:

  - create 000-prefix directory such as 0001,
  - copy the prefix htm or html files, and the prefix dir to the 0001 directory,
  - zip the 0001 directory to a 0001.zip file,
  - now move the 0001.zip file to the found directory.
  - Repeat the steps for every prefix such as 2,3,4, etc.

Finally check if the "found" directory contains all the zip files

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed response with the explanations! It helped me a lot.